# Convert one row into 3 rows and insert into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I have a select query with DB link which retrieves 15 columns per row from another DB.
I want to split the row retrieved and insert the data into three different tables.

Example:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... , column15 FROM table_x@db_link;
```

SELECT query result: Columns 01-15

Target Tables:
Table ABC: Columns 01-05;
Table XYZ: Columns 06-10;
Table PQR: Columns 11-15

Kindly suggest a way to do this. I am on Oracle 11g DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are describing [`insert all`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm):

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO ABC VALUES (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
  INTO XYZ VALUES (column6, column7, column8, column9, column10)
  INTO PQR VALUES (column11, column12, column13, column14, column15)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... , column15
  FROM table_x@db_link;
```